# Add custom menu in existing(Catalog) menu magento 2

Tags: magento2, menu

I'm using magento 2 and I would like to add a custom menu to my existing(catalog) menu. Basicly , I have my category CLOTHING that has DRESSES , PANTS ecc as subcategories, so basicly my navigation will show CLOTHING in the main menu. What I want is to have also DRESSES in the main menu , even if is not a category , I just want to have it twice (once inside clothing as subcategory , and once outside , next to clothing ) but I don't want to create it twice (once as subcategory and once as category , cause dresses is just a subcategory). How can I achieve this ?

Comment: please stop deleting and posting the same question over and over. This is the 3rd time you post this question.

Comment: I have tryed that , but it doesn't solve my issue.. you're welcome to join if you have something usefull to bring on..

Comment: I don't have something useful for now, but seeing the same question over and over again discourages me for looking for something useful. If you want you can edit the question anytime and add more useful info with your progress. Maybe someone can take it from there.